# JS : exported Function fail to return True/False

Tags: javascript, express

I have a function in another file , the function suppose to check if there is an admin in the DB, if not to create him . If by the end there is an admin in the DB (created or already was) , return true if not  it will return false.

```
/*AdminUser.js*/
const Admin = require('../models/admin');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
validate: function() {
    Admin.getAdminByRealID("1212", (error, admin) => {
        if (admin) {
            console.log("Main admin is Booted");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("Booting main admin");
            let newAdmin = new Admin({
                ID: "1212",
                account: {
                    username: "Admin",
                    password: "1212",
                    token: "Admin"
                },
                name: {
                    first: "Admin",
                    last: "Delta"
                },
                communication: {
                    email: "delta@example.com",
                    phone: "1212"
                }
            });
            Admin.addAdmin(newAdmin, (error, admin) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Admin reboot failed");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log("Admin have been initialized");
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

In the main app , I have this :

```
if (AdminUser.validate()) {
     app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
     });
} else {
     console.log('Fail to run Server');
     process.exit();
}
```

The function (.validate) always returns an 'undefined' object and the server fails to start . Can someone explain me why return value is not True/False .

The function(.validate) does print "Main admin is booted" and I guess it returns the true value next line.

Using app = express();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AdminUser.validate()` does indeed return `undefined`. If you look at the body of that function, you can see that it receives it's results via callbacks from `Admin.addAdmin` and `Admin.getAdminByRealID`. This means that to handle these results outside of the function body, you should provide a callback parameter to your `validate` method. This technique is pretty standard for node asynchronous programming (although Promises and `await` are more contemporary approaches - but that is outside of the scope of this answer).

```
const Admin = require('../models/admin');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = {
validate: function(done) {
    Admin.getAdminByRealID("1212", (error, admin) => {
        if (admin) {
            console.log("Main admin is Booted");
            done(true);
        } else {
            console.log("Booting main admin");
            let newAdmin = new Admin({
                ID: "1212",
                account: {
                    username: "Admin",
                    password: "1212",
                    token: "Admin"
                },
                name: {
                    first: "Admin",
                    last: "Delta"
                },
                communication: {
                    email: "delta@example.com",
                    phone: "1212"
                }
            });
            Admin.addAdmin(newAdmin, (error, admin) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Admin reboot failed");
                    done(false);
                } else {
                    console.log("Admin have been initialized");
                    done(true);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
}
```

And you would call it like so:

```
AdminUser.validate((ok)=> {
  if(ok){
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Fail to run Server');
    process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `validate()` function is asynchronous: it does not return anything when it's executed (quite literally, since it has no `return` instruction). Instead, it queries the database and does something when it's finished.

So in the main app, you can't just call `validate()` and expect to have a result; instead, you have to set it up so that when `validate()` finishes your app can go on. The classic way to do this is to use callbacks. Something like:

```
validate: function(callback) {
    ...
    if (error) {
        console.log("Admin reboot failed");
        callback(false);
    } else {
        console.log("Admin have been initialized");
        callback(true);
    }
    ...
}
```

Your snippet in the main app could be something like:

```
AdminUser.validate(function afterValidation(isValid) {
    if (isValid) {
        app.listen(port, () => {
            console.log('Server started on port: ' + port);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Fail to run Server');
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

The basic idea is that you give your async function something to do after it's finished, by passing a callback function to execute.